# Ajax-jquery get call to populate a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a `web service` get call from the url which contains an id. The url is `http://10.173.143.252:8181/cxf/crm/customerservice/customers/125`.

The url sends back a json response

```
{"id":125,"name":"John","password":"password","role":"user","privileges":["SMPP Balance Enquiry","Trigger SMPP Notification"],"status":"active"}
```

My ajax-jQuery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax(
    {
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://10.173.143.252:8181/cxf/crm/customerservice/customers/125",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         cache: false,
         success: function (data) {
              $.each(data, function () {
                  $("#personDataTable tbody").append("<tr>"+"<td>"+data.id+"</td>"
                                 +"<td>"+data.name+"</td>"
                                 +"<td>"+data.password+"</td>"
                                 +"<td>"+data.role+"</td>"
                                 +"<td>"+data.privileges+"</td>"
                                 +"<td>"+data.status+"</td>"
                                 +"</tr>" )

    //     trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.id[i] + '</td><td>' + data.name[i] + '</td><td>' + data.password[i] + '</td><td>' + data.role[i] + '</td><td>' + data.privileges[i] + '</td><td>' + data.status[i] + '</td></tr>';
    })
},
    error: function (msg) {

        alert(msg.responseText);
      }
   });
});
```

My html looks like:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="personDataTable">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>password</th>
        <th>role</th>
        <th>privileges</th>
        <th>status</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My approach looks proper to me. What could be the reason the table gets populated with 6 rows of the same data, on one reload. yes I have gone through many other links in `google`.

Comment: What error you are getting in console..?

Comment: `$.each(data.id` ? should  it be just `data`?

Comment: $.each(data.id, function (i, item) { instead use $.each(data, function (i, item) {

Comment: as you mentioned you response content, you don't have to use $.each to iterate, it is a single object so just try to access it like data.id and so on

Answer (score 0):

You have to first parse the json response in order to use it

```
parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Replace this line `$.each(data.id, function (i, item) {` with this

```
$.each(parsedData.id, function (i, item) {
```

Comment: Excepted if you explicitly said to jquery that you'll load JSON response.
He will automaticaly parse it and provide an object in the callback function.

It's the case here. You can see that 'dataType' is set to 'json', so data will be an object representing the parsed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
  "id": 125,
  "name": "John",
  "password": "password",
  "role": "user",
  "privileges": ["SMPP Balance Enquiry", "Trigger SMPP Notification"],
  "status": "active"
}

for (var key in data) {
  console.log(data[key])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="personDataTable">

  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>password</th>
    <th>role</th>
    <th>privileges</th>
    <th>status</th>

  </tr>

</table>
```

You can get value like this

Comment: Apologize for not being clear. I am trying to consume `http://10.173.143.252:8181/cxf/crm/customerservice/customers/125` web service .